# How to customize the status bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, dart-pub

I have created a flutter app and was checking on a physical device. I looked through the stack overflow for customizing the status bar and got few answers. But when I change the colour of the status bar, the whole status bar's colour changes (Including the battery indicator, mobile networks and other things.) due to which the contents become invisible. How can give separate colours for the contents of the status bar?

Any help will be appreciated.

Here's the code for status bar's colour change:

```
  import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    
    void main() {
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
        statusBarColor: Colors.black,
      ));
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
```

Here's what i am getting :

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.
Using statusBarIconBrightness, statusBarBrightness you can customize the Status bar icon and Brightness.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,// here what you need 
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light // here is what you need,
            statusBarColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
            systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8)),
        child: Scaffold(body: _buildScreenWidget()));
  };
```

You need to play with these properties until you get what you want.

Enjoy!!!

Comment: Thank you so much. It did the trick. Was stuck on this the whole day. :D